# How to get nodes in the new version of D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

The D3 examples I've seen use an old version of D3 with `tree.nodes(root).reverse()` to retrieve nodes array.
It does not work with the latest version of D3. How do I get nodes array in the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a tree layout object:

```
const layout = d3.tree();
```

Build a root object from your data:

```
const root = d3.hierarchy(data, d => d.children);
```

Extract nodes from the tree:

```
const tree = layout(root);
const nodes = tree.descendants();
```

Should work for **D3 V7** (see a working example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/918a64abe4c3682cac3b4c3c852a698d))